# Splash screen always shows same Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a splash screen, it opens when a app is launched. If user is already logged in, it opens main activity else it opens login page. But In my case it always opens main activity if the user is not logged in.

SplashScreen.kt

```
class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity)
        val details: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        if(details.getBoolean("login",false)){
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable { startActivity(Intent(this,
                MainActivity::class.java)) },500)
        }
        else{
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable { startActivity(Intent(this,
                LoginActivity::class.java)) },500)
        }

    }
}
```

LoginAcivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var login_button: Button
    lateinit var sign_up: TextView
    lateinit var password: TextView
    lateinit var mobile: TextView
    lateinit var progress_bar:ConstraintLayout
    lateinit var details:SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        details = getSharedPreferences("details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        details.edit().putBoolean("login",false).apply()
        mobile = findViewById(R.id.login_mobile_no)
        password = findViewById(R.id.login_password)
        login_button = findViewById(R.id.login_btn)
        sign_up = findViewById(R.id.login_sign_up)
        progress_bar = findViewById(R.id.login_prgs)
        sign_up.setOnClickListener {
            sign_up.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow)
            sign_up.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
                sign_up.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transaprency)
                sign_up.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                startActivity(Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java))
            },200)

        }
        login_button.setOnClickListener {
            login_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red)
            if(mobile.text.isNotBlank()&&password.text.isNotBlank()){
                if(Connection().checkConnectivity(this)) {
                    val q = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
                    val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v2/login/fetch_result/"
                    val jsonobj = JSONObject()
                    jsonobj.put("mobile_number", mobile.text.toString())
                    jsonobj.put("password", password.text.toString())
                    try{
                        progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        val jsonreq = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                            Request.Method.POST,url,jsonobj,
                            Response.Listener {
                                if(it.getJSONObject("data").getBoolean("success")){
                                    Toast.makeText(this,"Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                                    val fetched_data = it.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("data")
                                    details.edit().putBoolean("login",true).putString("user_id",fetched_data.getString("user_id"))
                                        .putString("name",fetched_data.getString("name"))
                                        .putString("email",fetched_data.getString("email"))
                                        .putString("mobile_number",fetched_data.getString("mobile_number"))
                                        .putString("address",fetched_data.getString("address")).apply()
                                    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))

                                }else{
                                    progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                                    Toast.makeText(this,"Mobile number or Password is incorrect.!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }

                            },
                            Response.ErrorListener {
                                progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                                Toast.makeText(this,"Please Try Again Later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }){
                            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                                headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                                headers["token"] = "c3acf1e14c21f9"
                                return headers
                            }
                        }
                        q.add(jsonreq)
                    }catch (e: Exception){
                        progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Try Again Later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Please Check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Enter the details Correctly..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
                login_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red)
            },200)

        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finishAffinity()
    }

}
```

I want the splash screen to open the respective activity, like if the user is logged in it has to open the `MainActivity` and if the user isn't logged in, it has to open the `LoginActivity`.

Comment: can you add SharedPreferences class for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a line when get "success" reply.

```
details.edit().putBoolean("login", true).commit()
```

otherwise the login entry in the shared preference is always "false".

Comment: Yes I do have it "details.edit().putBoolean("login",true).putString("user_id",fetched_data.getString("user_id")"

Comment: am also facing this issue you just change the login key and save data again, when you uninstall the app the issue is the same